# Regular expression to parse adjoining key-value pairs

Tags: c#, regex

Request your valuable time in helping me to find substring values using Regular Expressions..

This is my input

```
"ADMIN:YESEXT:NOBAT:NOBOM:NO"
```

I should be able to extract the following things to output

```
ADMIN:YES
EXT:NO
BAT:NO
BOM:NO
```

I used the following regex to get just the ADMIN: string
`^\s?(?:ADMIN:)`
How should i modify the regex expression to get the required output

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
(\w+):(YES:NO)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the value following the colon will always be `YES` or `NO`? I'd say, you want something like

```
/([^:]+):(YES|NO)/g
```

Where `$1` is the property and `$2` its value.

Comment: The question is tagged as C# and this looks to be a javascript regular expression from formatting and the suffix of a global flag

Comment: well yes, i'll have to admit to not having noticed the tags. i just treated it as a regex question, and answered it as such. i'd argue that this is more of a question of regex strategy than syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching this regex:

```
(.*?):(YES|NO)
```

Comment: Nice. This regexp uses a lazy quantifer ( the question mark after .* ). to locate the correct colon character. But this regexp has a small mistake. The asterix (*) has to applied on the whole expression and not only to (YES|NO). So this would become: "((.*?):(YES|NO))*"

Answer (score 1):

`([^:]+):(YES|NO)` will do. This will match all text followed by :YES or :NO

Answer (score 0):

```
(ADMIN|EXT|BAT|BOM):(YES|NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values out in an explicit order, then you can use:

```
^\s?(?:ADMIN:(YES|NO))(?:EXT:(YES|NO))(?:BAT:(YES|NO))(?:BOM:(YES|NO))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
\w*:(NO|YES)

\w*      - match as many word-charachters as possible  
:        - match a colon  
(NO|YES) - match YES or NO
```

To get all results, you can use something like:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\w*:(NO|YES)");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(theStringToSearch);
while (matchResults.Success) {
   //take us of matchResults....

   matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp suggested by @soulmerge uses a lazy quantifer ( the question mark after .* ). to locate the correct colon character. 
But this regexp has a small mistake. The asterix (*) has to be applied on the whole expression and not only to (YES|NO).

So this would become:

```
((.*?):(YES|NO))*
```

I tried to comment to his answer but the regexp was not getting displayed properly.

Comment: That will match the whole string in one go, but @soulmerge's regex (like most of the others) is meant for iterating through the tokens via the `Matches()` method or repeated calls to `Match()`.  By the way, you can use backticks to format code, both in posts and in comments.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. I have been making such mistakes all over SO lately. Thankfully SO users have been lenient enough not to downvote my answers but only point out my mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner

```
string Content = @"ADMIN:YESEXT:NOBAT:NOBOM:NO";
string Pattern = @"([^:]+):(YES|NO)";

Dictionary<string, string> dict = Regex.Matches(Content, Pattern).Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Then dump dictionary key/value pairs as desired.